# ${maven.build.timestamp} can not show in JSF page

Tags: jsf, maven-3

I want to show ${maven.build.timestamp} value on page JSf page. But it seems not work. What I can see is just "${maven.build.timestamp}". I check version.txt in Target folder. I can see the date correctly. But it seems can't show on JSF page. Does anyone has some idea about that. Thanks.
pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

version.txt

```
version=${project.version}
build.date=${timestamp}
```

JSF

```
<h:outputLabel value="Version #{msg['version']} - #{msg['build.date']}"/>
```

Comment: I can see the version is shown correctly. But build time can't work normally. Strange

Comment: How exactly is this a JSF problem? Are you saying that Maven has correctly set the value in version.txt? JSF is merely the presenter here, not the builder. And why exactly did you think that all of that CSS is  relevant to the actual problem? I.e. does the problem really disappear when you remove or change at least one of those `style` properties? Please reduce irrelevant noise from the question to make it better understandable and answerable. Not only for us, but also for yourself. Try to think logically.